# CSS position/layout to have DIVs flow around a DIV?

Tags: css, css-float

This is extremely difficult to explain, so I've created a fiddle to help:

http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/VRZef/

Size the panes so that the first row of boxes goes from 0 to 10. Click on box 13. What I'd LIKE to have happen is have those four empty spaces to the left of box 13 be filled with 20, 21, 28, and 29. In other words, I want the boxes to wrap completely to the left and flow AROUND box 13. Is this doable?

Comment: Good question. I think it isn't doable with the same floating div without individual positions on each, or table instead of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible in pure (modern browser supported) CSS.

I would recommend checking out [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). It is a jQuery plugin that handles this in JavaScript.

Comment: Nice. But it doesn't appear to adjust/reflow boxes when I increase the size of one of them.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack You'll want to use [`.masonry('reload')`](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/methods.html)

Comment: Ah! Ok, that works, but unfortunately you can't see the box expanding in realtime. The box expands underneath the other boxes, and then when the expand animation is done, masonry reflows everything.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack You could, in theory reflow at every step but that would be costly. The other option is to wrap them in a containing `<div>`, set that width immediately, then reflow and animate the other width.

Comment: Ah never mind! A little z-index change upon clicking works well enough for my purposes. Thanks!